# Background Processing

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am developing a Magento extension.
My extension optimizes all sever files. 
But if I leave this page that is executing this, in other words when I click something else in the menu, the processing is stopped.

So I have to repeat it manually.
I guess to do it I need multi task processing or thread processing.

I want to continue this process though I click another page such as manage product option.

Is it possible?  Must I use cron?

So I am trying to do just bellow.

```
protected function optimizeAllAction() {

ignore_user_abort(true);  //I apply here

$steps = 2;
$this->blockImages = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('imagerecycle/images');
$images = $this->blockImages->_getLocalImages();  
include_once(__DIR__.'/../Helper/Data.php');
$helper = new Imagerecycle_Imagerecycle_Helper_Data();

foreach ($images as $image) {
    if ($image['optimized'] === false) {
        if ($steps === 0) {
            $this->ajaxReponse(true, array('continue' => true, 'totalImages' => $this->blockImages->getTotalImages(), 'totalOptimizedImages' => $this->blockImages->getTotalOptimizedImages()));
        }

        $returned = $helper->optimize($image['filename']);                
        if ($returned === false) {
            $this->ajaxReponse(false);
        }
        $steps--;
    }
}
}
```

is it right?

Comment: were you able to solve this? Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right using PHP's `ignore_user_abort(true)` function. You might also need to add `set_time_limit(0)` cause the script might hit the time limit and terminate.

Adding this to the top of your controller's action method will continue to execute the PHP code all the way if the user/client has aborted the request.

Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

You could add some `Mage::log()`'s in your code to see if it is still running. Check `var/log/system.log` if the lines appear.

Alternatively, you could setup a cron job to process this. This needs a lot more explanation. One hint I can give for this is that you need to set a flag that indicates it should be ran or build a queue that the cron job can process.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot. Because I am running on Windows by using Xampp. I don't know how can log and read it.

Comment: I don't think it is easy. Please let me know anther method.

Comment: If you don't know how to view `var/log/system.log` then I don't know. This is a pretty essential thing if you're developing in Magento.

Comment: I use the  Mage::log($image['filename']);   So I review the system.log file.

Comment: But when I click another page, the register is ended.

Comment: I guess when the another controller is called, the old controller class will be died. What do u think about it?